# Mysql on duplicate key update the same row

Tags: mysql

So what I want to do is if image is duplicate to write image to image2 column, but in the same row not a new one as the code below does.

```
 $sql = "insert into uploads(description,lat,lng,image,name) 
 values('$name','$lat','$lng','$image','$name')
 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
 description=$name,lat=$lat,lng=$lng,image=image2,name=$name";
```

Comment: do you want if user upload image with same name, should rename it with another ?

Comment: I want to have 1 row with multiple images, so if the name matches I add another image

Comment: Working of this query depends of table structure, what columns are keys in your table?

Comment: please edit your question cause question doesn't clear for me ?

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/jrV9N <- key structure

Comment: Freddy I want instead of having multiple rows with the same name and different images, to have one that  with multiple image columns.

Comment: `if image is duplicate ` - and **how** should MySQL determine if image is duplicate? What's the unique key? Description? Lat? Lng? Image? Name?  `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` works **only** if you try to add a row with value that already exists (is made `unique`). Do you know what `unique` key is? How do you mark image as duplicate at all? What's the logic behind it? Do you think MySQL looks at image contents as a human would and determines a record is a duplicate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to achieve this only via mysql, then go for below approach:

**Add unique index on field image**

```
ALTER TABLE `uploads`.`test` ADD UNIQUE `imageIndex` (`image`);
```

**Then use query:**

```
$sql = "insert into uploads(description,lat,lng,image,name) 
 values('$name','$lat','$lng','$image','$name')
 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE image2=$image
```

**One of the recommended solution can be:**

First do a select query to check whether image exists in table :

```
$rowWithImage = Select * from uploads where image = '$image';
```

If above results in some result,then you can do a direct upload.

```
$sql = "update table uploads set image2=$image where id = '$rowWithImage["id"]' "
```

Hope you get the logic, do minor syntax + logic correction based on what your application requires.

Comment: Your answer, while correct, uses a field that might be too long for indexing.  This answer would be more complete if you were to calculate the hash of the image and then make that unique. Such approach lets you have fixed-length unique key that's related to variable-length value.

Comment: Yes you are correct @Mjh. Ideally the problem itself should be handled at application layer rather than directly via query, i gave solution considering that it is utmost necessary for answer seeker to do it via mysql. Also depends on number of rows in the table for which question is asked.

Comment: Mjh can you give me any tip of how to calculate hash of image?

Comment: I made image/image2 to be references so I don't bump into the problem of long indexing.

Answer (score 0):

You are not including the id in your query, and this is the key, so always is going to be new because it is automatically asigned during insertion

Comment: So if I assign name as primary key and delete id would it work?

Comment: Yes, this is one way